# Is it possible to install Windows Vista 64-bit on mid 2010 27" iMac w/ Mavericks?

Tags: imac, bootcamp, partition, windows

I have a legal copy of Vista which I used to use before I had a drive failure on my mid 2010 27" iMac. Since then I've installed OSX Mavericks, and now it's telling me that only Windows 7 and 8 are supported via Boot Camp.

I tried circumventing this by booting from the Vista disk, but it won't let me install because now OSX uses GPT instead of MBR (or so it seems). I really don't want to have to buy Windows 7 since I only need Windows for a few games. Is there any way around or am I stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using Boot Camp, just make this few steps:

1. Install rEFIt.
2. Resize your disk so you get some free space for vista.
3. Create a new partition from that free space.
4. Boot up your Mac with the Vista install disk inserted.
5. Install Vista onto the new created partition.

If you need a more detailed How-To/Tutorial/Manual/Assist (or what ever you will call it), have a look here http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required

Comment: You will still need the Boot Camp support software, with the drivers on it. I'd recommend getting hold of a version of those for an earlier version of Boot Camp that does support Vista, though

Comment: I think they are on my snow leopard dvd, right?

Comment: you can use Boot Camp to only create the driver cd/dvd. But you may get into trouble if you have a new Mac and would like to install an older OS such as XP or Vista. There is a Disscussion about that on the Apple Page https://discussions.apple.com/message/18697939